# Using chartist in Jenkins throws - TypeError: self is undefined

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jelly, chartist.js

Trying to use chartist.js in a jenkins plugin.
I've imported the libary with cdn - regular import (and the css).

But I get "TypeError: self is undefined" in the browser debug instead of showing the chart. I'm using the most simple chartist.js example from  their site.

This is the source code of the function that creates the error:

```js
  /**
   * Adds one or a space separated list of classes to the current element and ensures the classes are only existing once.
   *
   * @memberof Chartist.Svg
   * @param {String} names A white space separated list of class names
   * @return {Chartist.Svg} The wrapper of the current element
   */
  function addClass(names) {
    this._node.setAttribute('class',
      this.classes(this._node)
        .concat(names.trim().split(/\s+/))
        .filter(function(elem, pos, self) {
          return self.indexOf(elem) === pos;
        }).join(' ')
    );

    return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating the libary folder with the latest version of chartist from the GitHub repository -
https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/tree/develop

Simply copy the 'dist' folder to the equivalent folder in the npm node-modules path in your program / Jenkins plugin.